# Are JOIN conditions better than WHERE clauses in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have come to see that you can do the same thing with either one much of the time. Is any way of doing it more performant in certain circumstances? Is one considered better than the other in terms of readability? Does SQL Server compile them into the same thing anyway?

An example:

```
SELECT c.customer_name
,      o.order_id
FROM customers AS c
JOIN orders AS o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id AND o.order_total > 50.00
```

VS

```
SELECT c.customer_name
,      o.order_id
FROM customers AS c
JOIN orders AS o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.order_total > 50.00
```

Please excuse me if I am severely misunderstanding something about this or my syntax is incorrect.

1. I'm pretty new to SQL and much of the logic in the application I work on at my new job is in dynamic SQL (I just started my first development job 2 weeks ago)
2. This is my first Stack Overflow question
3. I had to adapt a fake query from the ones I see at work, so what I gave as an example might not even be correct syntax. Every time I think I understand how things work I soon realize that no, it's not that simple.

Comment: This is really a matter of personal preference although one of the two options might perform better depending on your system but it could be either method which performs better. Personally I stick to using the actual join condition as the join condition which in your example is `c.customer_id = o.customer_id` and keep the filter condition as a filter or where clause i.e. `o.order_total > 50.00`

Comment: Both of your queries should have identical execution plans, run `EXPLAIN` on each to verify this.  If you were doing a left join instead of an inner join, the two queries would be different.

Comment: I suggest you turn on "Display Actual Execution Plan" and view the actual plan for both options to see whether they are different or not. And whether a different plan is used may well vary depending on the query, the indexes available etc. There are very few hard and fast rules when it comes to T-SQL.

Comment: @DaleK This is not a matter of personal preference. It's a matter of semantics. True, with an inner join it boils down to readability, but with outer joins it can have a significant impact on the result of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on JOIN type.
For INNER JOINS there is no difference, optimizer will treat them the same.
For OUTER JOINS there is a key difference.
For following query:

```
SELECT * FROM employee AS e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN department AS d ON e.depId=d.depId AND d.location = 'USA'
```

It will return all employees and join USA departments.

```
SELECT * FROM employee AS e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN department AS d ON e.depId=d.depId
WHERE d.location = 'USA'
```

This one will return only employees in USA departments (in other words it will convert the join to INNER JOIN).

Comment: Thank you, that's an important distinction. I was specifically referring to inner joins. Should I edit the question to reflect that or leave it in it's less specific state for posterity?